# IEEE 754 Floating Point

Tags: ieee-754, equivalence

Could someone explain to me why these do not equal in IEEE 754 floating point:

```
(1 + 1e300) - 1e100 and 1 + (1e300 - 1e100)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post code and output. I frankly don't believe you.

Comment: Would also be a good idea to say what programming language you are using.

Comment: They should be equal (both being the floating point representation of 1e300).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on precisely *which* IEEE floating point format you're working in, and the rounding mode that you are using.

**F64**

The comments above that say that they are equal are most likely checking this in at least double (F64 binary) precision with e.g. RNE rounding. This is what usually happens when using `double` in C-like languages.

In that case, all of your numbers get converted and rounded to an F64 value. The other numbers are so far apart from 1e300 that any addition will round back to roughly 1e300. To display this number in decimals, it gets rounded again and shown as 1e300.

If your rounding mode is not RNE, your final answers may be slightly different from 1e300, although still probably equal.

**F32**

However, if you are working in single (F32) precision - most of your numbers are much too large to represent, and will likely be converted to an `Inf`.

Following the IEEE 745 rules: you end up calculating `Inf-Inf` in both cases, which should result in `NaN`. Then finally, if you end up comparing the values as floats: `NaN==NaN`, the answer must be `false`, which appears to be consistent with what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For Python,

```
>>> (1 + 1e300) - 1e100 == 1 + (1e300 - 1e100)
True
```